# render textarea control with react-bootstrap and react-redux-form

Tags: reactjs, react-redux-form

I'm currently rendering input controls like so:

```
renderField = function({ input, label, name, type, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) {
    return (
      <FormGroup>
        <FormControl {...input} type={type} placeholder={label} />
        {touched && error && <span className="error-text">{error}</span>}
      </FormGroup>
    );
  }

  render() {
    const { handleSubmit, pristine, error } = this.props;

    return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(this.onSubmit)} className="profile-form">
        <Field name="first_name" component={this.renderField} type="text" label="First Name" />
        <Field name="last_name" component={this.renderField} type="text" label="Last Name" />
        <Field name="bio" component={this.renderField} type="text" label="Bio" />
        ...

        <Button bsStyle="primary" type="submit" disabled={pristine}>Save Changes</Button>
      </form>
    );
  }
```

I want to change the bio field to be a textarea control instead of an input. Is it possible to do this within my `renderField` function. I'd like to do it there instead of having to replicate for another function such as `renderTextArea` since that would duplicate a lot of the arguments and bootstrap markup.

I'm not seeing any examples of this in the docs or searches but maybe I'm thinking about it wrong.

Comment: What if you will change `this.renderField` to `field => this.renderField({...field, class: 'textarea'})` and add `componentClass={class}` in renderField?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

thanks to @elmeister for the comment to lead in the right direction. I was missing the componentClass prop, so on the bio field I just needed to change to

```
<Field name="bio" component={this.renderField} type="text" label="Bio" componentClass="textarea" />
```

and then in my renderField method I needed to add componentClass as an argument and add that prop to the `FormControl` component. I didn't need to change input to field btw, i think componentClass just overrides it when passed in.

```
renderField = ({ input, label, name, type, componentClass, meta: { touched, error, warning } }) => {
    return (
      <FormGroup>
        <ControlLabel>{label}</ControlLabel>
        <FormControl {...input} componentClass={componentClass} type={type} placeholder={label} />
        {touched && error && <span className="error-text">{error}</span>}
      </FormGroup>
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `Control` with `FormControl` straightaway.

```
export const InputFieldComponent = ({
                                     id,
                                     type,
                                     label,
                                     fieldObject,
                                     placeHolder,
                                     maxLength,
                                     srOnly,
                                     messages, validators, onChange}: Props) => (
 <FormGroup controlId={id} validationState={fieldObject.valid ? 'success' : 'error'>
   <ControlLabel srOnly={srOnly}>{label}</ControlLabel>
   <Control
     model={`.${id}`}
     type={type}
     placeHolder={ placeHolder || label }
     component={FormControl}
     maxLength={maxLength}
     validators={validators}
     onChange={onChange}
   >
   <FormControl.Feedback> <FaCheck /> </FormControl.Feedback>
   <Errors
    show="touched"
    model={`.${id}`}
    wrapper={ (v) => <HelpBlock>{v}</HelpBlock> }
    messages={messages}
   />
 </FormGroup>
);

InputFieldComponent.defaultProps = {
 messages: {},
 srOnly: false,
 type: 'text',
 maxLength: 255
}

export default InputFieldComponent;
```